# How would you populate asp:GridView with List<List<string>> in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I tried searching it in Google but I seem to keep bumping in to two dimensional arrays solutions like this one: http://forums.asp.net/t/1318173.aspx/1 
Do I have to convert my `List<List<string>>` in to a two-dimensional array list?

Comment: What does your data look like? How do you want it to display? A list of strings is intuitively liner, but a list of list of strings is conceptually two-dimensional, so how do you want to display it in the grid view?

Comment: What if not all of your inner lists are of the same size?

Comment: @BeemerGuy.net my data is from an sql database search I made. so with a List<List<string>> roomresults, roomresults[a][b], where a is the column name and b is each row

Answer (score 0):

If you want everything to be flattened out (that is, each list is shown one after the other), you can do this:

```
var orig = new List<List<string>>();
var flat = orig.SelectMany(inner => inner).ToList();
```

Now you can use `flat` to bind to the `GridView` and it will contain a single list that is the flattening of each of the inner lists.

However, if you want each outer list element to be a row, and each inner list element to be a column you inherently have a problem if the inner lists are each of different size (or if they can be). You need to describe what you expect in this scenario.

---

Alternatively, just turn your lists into arrays if you think the link provided gives you your answer:

```
string[][] test = orig.Select(inner => inner.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Comment: roomresults[a][b] where a is the column and b is the row. I created the List from a sql search I made from a database.

Comment: You haven't answered the question as to what happens if your lists are of different sizes?